# Force conditional page count using Apache FOP

Tags: xsl-fo

I have an XSL-FO stylesheet to transform XML documents to PDF using the Apache FOP formatter. The output PDF should always have a page count that is divisible by 4, so that page count mod 4 = 0.

The stylesheet has 3 page-sequence elements: one for frontmatter, one for the body, and one for backmatter. If the total number of pages of those sequences combined does not equal 0 on mod 4, then blank pages should be added after the last sequence until it does.

My question is: is this even possible using Apache FOP or any other formatter? I believe the [`force-page-count`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#force-page-count) attribute is meant for this kind of requirement, but it seems to be limited to an odd or even number of pages, not a certain amount of pages.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  You can't do that with XSL 1.1 as written, and I don't see anything in the FOP 2.5 documentation that says that FOP can do it.

With AH Formatter, you can force the page count for the `fo:page-sequence` based on either the number of pages in the current page sequence or the number of pages counting from the beginning of the document (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-ext.html#axf.force-page-count). AFAICT, RenderX lets you force the page count for the current `fo:page-sequence` to be a multiple of a number (see http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#ftn.d57e9408).

Comment: Thank you for confirming, Tony. I'm going to look into the formatters you mentioned or maybe look for another solution to this problem altogether.

Comment: Tony is correct. You could use the Intermediate Format to count pages and add blank pages as needed.